# Sharing large objects in multiprocessing pools

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing

I'm trying to revisit [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22487296/multiprocessing-in-python-sharing-large-object-e-g-pandas-dataframe-between) slightly older question and see if there's a better answer these days.

I'm using python3 and I'm trying to share a large dataframe with the workers in a pool.  My function reads the dataframe, generates a new array using data from the dataframe, and returns that array.  Example code below (**note**: in the example below I do not actually use the dataframe, but in my code I do).

```
def func(i):
    return i*2

def par_func_dict(mydict):

    values = mydict['values']
    df = mydict['df']

    return pd.Series([func(i) for i in values])

N = 10000
arr = list(range(N))
data_split = np.array_split(arr, 3)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,10))

pool = Pool(cores)

gen = ({'values' : i, 'df' : df} 
       for i in data_split)

data = pd.concat(pool.map(par_func_dict,gen), axis=0)

pool.close()
pool.join()
```

I'm wondering if there's a way I can prevent feeding the generator with copies of the dataframe to prevent taking up so much memory.

The answer to the link above suggests using `multiprocessing.Process()`, but from what I can tell, it's difficult to use that on top of functions that return things (need to incorporate signals / events), and the comments indicate that each process still ends up using a large amount of memory.

Comment: The comments on the other thread don't say how they are measuring the memory usage... many platforms will include shared memory when reporting the memory usage of a process.

Comment: I guess one possible solution is to make `df` a global variable.  Not ideal, but as long as none of the processes actually edit it, I think it should be okay.

Comment: I would also look into other ways to parallelize the work, such as [`dask`](http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe.html).

Comment: @soundstripe: I've seen a few talks on `dask`. Haven't had a chance to experiment with it yet, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: You can also try joblib : https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parallel.html  . See using shared objects with joblib here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46657885/how-to-write-to-a-shared-variable-in-python-joblib